# comparing two structures C

Tags: c, struct, typedef, equality

I have defined a structure called cache using typedef and I have a function which takes as an argument a cache. I have also created three instances of cache. The function is called in my main method and depending on the situation I pass a different instance of cache to it. How can I check within the method which instance has been passed? I tried `==` but the error I get is `== illegal for struct`. How can I conduct this check?

`

```
cache first_cache;
cache second_cache;
cache third_cache;

void function_example(cache user_cache, int size) {
    if (cache == first_cache) {
    ...
    }
    else if (cache == second_cache) {

    }
```

`

Comment: Compare each member of the `cache struct` one at a time, or perhaps compare the memory the cache consumes?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to put an `uniqueID` in the structure, and then compare the IDs.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense @user3386109, I think it's the simplest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can just compare the addresses: `&first_cache == &second_cache`. You'd want to pass the *address* of `cache` as a parameter, otherwise you'll be comparing a copy on the stack:

```
void function_example(cache * user_cache, int size) {
    if (user_cache == &first_cache) {
```

Comment: If I pass the address of the cache as a parameter, how do I then manipulate the cache inside the if statement? Before I just performed operations directly on user_cache, but if I pass a pointer to user_cache how do I access the actual cache within the if statement

Comment: Instead of `somecache.foo` you would use `somecache->foo` or `(*somecache)->foo`. But, since you check which `cache` the `user_cache` it is, you can just use `first_cache.foo` etc. You should probably search for `C pointers` and read an introduction to understand them, just knowing the syntax won't be enough.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: not `(somecache)->foo` byt `(*somecache).foo`. The `*` undoes the `&` so you can use a `.` again, but at the cost of having to type `()`. (See, it gets tricky when mixing `->` and `.` ;-))

Comment: Let me clarify, my cache definition contains for example `cache_block *array_block;` which I loop through using `cache.array_block[i]`... So if I want to do this here on the `user_cache` what would I have to type?

Comment: I will for sure take the time to understand C pointers, but at the moment I am so piled with coursework and exams that I just want this to work tbh

Comment: If this question is about homework, I feel [I should warn you](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) - Although this answer answers your question, it looks like a short-cut. If pointers haven't been covered in your course yet, then your approach is likely not what is intended and even though it *works*, it may be graded in a way you don't expect. As the other answer by David suggests, if you provide some more code we can better see whether your approach is the best one in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

From you last two comments, "for example `cache_block *array_block;` which I loop through using `cache.array_block[i]...` So if I want to do this here on the `user_cache`" does not make a whole lot of sense based on the code you have posted. The only way that would make sense is if your `struct cache` contains a nested array of type `struct cache_block` (e.g. a member declared as `cache_block *array_block;` which has been assigned the address of an allocated or statically declared populated array of type `cache_block`. If that is not the case, please clarify. Specifically by adding a minimum, complete and verifiable example to your questions (see: [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) )

What you need to pass to `function_example` will depend on how your structures are declared and in what scope. Since you are only passing a single struct to your function, the `cache` you are testing against must be global or you would have nothing to test against. Without seeing how the structs are declared or what the exact members are the best anyone can to is try to help you by helping with struct comparisons in a general sense.

To compare your structs you have two basic ways to approach the comparison. For lack of better words, the two ways can be described as a *deep* comparison (where you are comparing the value or contents of each of the struct members against those in a second struct of the same type, one at a time), or a *shallow* comparison (where you make a bitwise comparison of the memory located at each of the structs addresses as a whole). (the *shallow/deep* verbiage is generally associated with a *copy* operation rather than a comparison, but it is a direct correlation).

Since in your comment you do not want to worry about handling the structs as pointers, you will be passing a copy of your struct (or both a reference struct, and your struct to compare against) to your function. Both avenues of comparison are available regardless of how you pass the structs. To make a bitwise comparison to determine if your structs are equal, you can use `memcmp` to compare the two blocks of memory holding each struct. Without knowing how your `cache` is declared, a reference struct to test against is passed as `test` and your user cache struct is passed as `user`. An example of the comparison would be:

```
void function_example(cache test, cache user)
{
    if (memcmp (&test, &user, sizeof test) == 0) {
        printf ("  test cache = user cache\n");
        return;
    }
    printf ("  test cache != user cache\n");
}
```

Without seeing the remainder of your code, it isn't possible to match your exact struct, but regardless, the test above will provide a comparison of whether the contents of two structs are equivalent regardless of what the members are.

(**note:** A caveat is if your struct contains pointers to other memory locations that are not contained as part of the memory occupied by your struct. In that case, you cannot compare the struct contents by a bitwise *shallow* comparison of the struct alone and a member-by-member comparison would be required where the memory referenced by the pointer members could also be compared)

A full example using the above function with simple example members could look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    char str[10];
} cache;

void function_example(cache test, cache user);

int main (void) {

    cache first_cache = { 1, 2, "cat" };
    cache second_cache = { 2, 1, "dog" };
    cache third_cache = { 1, 2, "cat" };

    cache test_cache;

    memcpy (&test_cache, &second_cache, sizeof second_cache);

    printf ("\ntesting first_cache:\n");
    function_example (test_cache, first_cache);

    printf ("\ntesting second_cache:\n");
    function_example (test_cache, second_cache);

    printf ("\ntesting third_cache:\n");
    function_example (test_cache, third_cache);

    return 0;
}

void function_example(cache test, cache user)
{
    if (memcmp (&test, &user, sizeof test) == 0) {
        printf ("  test cache = user cache\n");
        return;
    }
    printf ("  test cache != user cache\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/cmpstruct

testing first_cache:
  test cache != user cache

testing second_cache:
  test cache = user cache

testing third_cache:
  test cache != user cache
```

Obviously this is a simplistic comparison and does not contain a looping comparison you seek in your comments, but without more, it would simply be a guess. If you will edit your question and add the remainder of your code, I'm happy to work with your further to help you achieve what you are attempting.